# Open a fixed file from a project (in Emacs Projectile)

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-helm

How can I code a function to open the same relative file (for example, `server/logfile.txt`) from a project?  So, this should be relative to the project I'm in.

`projectile-find-file` list all of them, not only the one which we're interested to open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `projectile-project-root` function to expand paths relative to your projectile project's base directory, eg.

```
(when-let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
  (find-file-other-window (expand-file-name "server/logfile.txt" root)))
```

or (the `when-let`, `if-let` macros are from `subr-x` included in recent emacses)

```
(if-let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
    (find-file-other-window (expand-file-name "server/logfilt.txt" root))
  (user-error "not projectile project found"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a non projectile way would be to use `bookmarks` feature of `emacs`? For an already defined bookmark `C-x r b` would take you to the file and offset within it?